# Are they all adjectives? (Off-kilter something fierce)

Tags: adjectives

I can't figure out whether the words in question are adjectives? Do they all modify the same word at the same time? Can "something" modify the word "fierce" while "off-kilter" and "fierce" describe the collocation "color balance"?

> The color balance is off-kilter something fierce, veering heavily toward the red pole of the spectrum. 
>   (The example is from Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/something-fierce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Off-kilter" is an adjective modifying the word "color balance". The phrase 
"something fierce", however, modifies the adjective "off-kilter": it's a colloquial way of saying "very much" or "extremely". Thus, "something fierce" would be considered to be an adverbial phrase. Some other phrases like this are "something awful" = "awfully", something terrible" = "terribly".

Comment: I agree. It's my sense that "something fierce" (i.e. to a great degree, terribly, extremely) is an Americanism.